# Fast Fourier Transform of exp(-x^2) in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have to calculate numerically the 2nd derivative of a Gaussian function: [image: \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} f(x) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}e^{-ax^2} = -2axe^{-ax^2}]
I've read every question on this topic here, but can't come to a good result. I've chosen NumPy as my tool of choice.

The instructions from our professor :

1. Get an `x` array of size `N = 128` with step `dx = 1`. So, `-64, -63, ..., 62, 63`. Calculate `f(x)`
2. Perform FFT on `f(x)` and receive the transformed array `f_m`.
3. Multiply `f_m` by [image: (jk)^2], where [image: j] is imaginary unit, [image: q=2] is degree of derivation and
   [image: x]
4. Perform an inverse FFT to receive the derivative.
5. In some FFT implementations you may have to scale by `1/n` (but that's the smallest problem now)

Now here is my code, as simple as possible.

```
import numpy as np

# Set some parameters
n = 128
dx = 1
a = 0.001

# Create x, calculate f(x) and its FFT
x = np.arange(-n/2, n/2) * dx
psi = np.exp(-a * x * x)
f_m = np.fft.fft(psi)

# k_m creation according to professor (point 3. in my instruction)
k_m = np.arange(-n/2, n/2, dtype=float)
k_m[:int(n / 2)] = (2 * np.pi * k_m[:int(n / 2)]) / (n * dx)
k_m[int(n / 2):] = (2 * np.pi * (k_m[int(n / 2):] - n)) / (n * dx)

# Multiply f_m by (j * k_m)^q. For q=2, this is -k_m^2
f_m *= -k_m * k_m
# Inverse FFT on the result to get the second derivative and scale by 1 / n
f_m = np.fft.ifft(f_m) / n
```

One thing that I can't get is the result still has imaginary part and so something is not right. Can anybody help there?

EDIT: Cris Luengo's answer works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
k_m = np.arange(-n/2, n/2, dtype=float)
```

The instructions in step 3 talk about `m` going from 0 to `n-1`. The code should look like this:

```py
k_m = np.arange(0, n, dtype=float)
half = int(n / 2) + 1;  # notice the + 1 here!
k_m[:half] = (2 * np.pi * k_m[:half]) / (n * dx)
k_m[half:] = (2 * np.pi * (k_m[half:] - n)) / (n * dx)
```

The FFT produces an output where the first element (index 0) is the 0 frequency, not a frequency `-n/2`.

Your current version of the `k_m` array might be correct if you use `fftshift` to shift the 0 frequency bin to the middle of the array, though I'm not completely sure of that (maybe the `-n` in the second half should be removed?).

---

Finally, the division by `n` is not necessary here:

```
f_m = np.fft.ifft(f_m) / n
```

The NumPy IFFT is already normalized.

And remember to plot `f_m.real`, after verifying that the imaginary component is almost zero (these values should differ from zero only because of numerical rounding errors).

If you make `a` a little larger, for example `a=0.005`, then your input Gaussian fits entirely in the input signal, and you won't have ugly edge effects from filtering a signal that is cut off.

Comment: Thanks for answer. After changing to `f_m = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(psi))` and `k_m = np.arange(0, n, dtype=float)` it still doesn't work though...

Comment: @lkky7: Yes, you should do **one** of those two things, not both.

Comment: Thank you, and that changed something, but it's still a bad result. And removing the `-n` doesn't change that too :( Added result to edit

Comment: @lkky7 When I run your code with my changes, I do see a correct 2nd derivative. Note that you are comparing it with the first derivative in your graph. You have also scaled down the result by a factor `n`, which you shouldn't do. The result does have an ugly edge effect, if you make `a` larger this effect should be reduce. Note also that you need to ignore the (nearly zero) imaginary component, and plot `f_m.real`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do with a simpler `k`, as long as you perform a correct FT shift at some point, which implements under the hood the same as your instructor or @CrisLuengo have written explicitly.

```
import numpy as np


# Set some parameters
n = 128
dx = 1
a = 0.001

# Create x, calculate f(x) and its FFT
x = np.arange(-n // 2, n // 2) * dx
f_x = np.exp(-a * x ** 2)
dd_f_x = 2 * a * np.exp(-a * x ** 2) * (2 * a * x ** 2 - 1)

f_k = np.fft.fft(f_x)
k = np.fft.ifftshift(np.arange(-n // 2, n // 2))
k = (2 * np.pi * k / (n * dx))
dd_f_k = -k ** 2 * f_k
dd_f_x_ = np.fft.ifft(dd_f_k)
```

which works as expected:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, squeeze=True)
ax.plot(x, dd_f_x_.real, label='∂²/∂x² f(x) with DFT')
ax.plot(x, dd_f_x, label='∂²/∂x² f(x)')
ax.legend()
```

[image: plot]